# What does ちゃい in やっちゃいねぇ mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Context:

> おれはおれの信念に後悔するような事は何一つ**やっちゃい**ねぇ！これからもそうだ！

What does the ちゃい in やっちゃい mean?  I suppose it's not やっちゃう aka やってしまう...

Comment: Welcome to JLSE! We generally frown on asking questions like this, because it looks like a simple translation question. It looks like you're trying to understand what the ～っちゃい form is short for. It's good that you've included what you think it *isn't*, (but for the record, why do you think it is not やっちゃう) but if you reword your question to ask about the underlying grammar of what is troubling you, it will be less likely to be closed. http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se

Comment: No I don't need the translation nor did I post it for translation purposes ... I could understand that point of view if I were asking e.t.c what 夢 means but I believe it's obvious the ending, not the verb, troubles me ... I understand the verb is most propably やる but I'm not familiar with the ending. 
I suppose it's not やってしまう because of the ending い on the give sentence (meaning the uncut form would be やってしまい？No sense for me on that either)
Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: I know you weren't looking for a translation, that's why I suggested you reword your question, not change it. And I don't really know but I would guess that it's just short for やっちゃいない.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

やっちゃいねえ here is a combination shortened/colloquial version of やってはいない.

ない>ねえ is a change that happens frequently in colloquial masculine speech (which this pretty obviously is, it's got おれ also).

やっちゃ is a shortening of やっては. You're generally allowed to put a topic particle between the two halves of a -て+VERB construction (unless the verb is しまう).